# Is a VPN right for restricting server access?

Tags: linux, security, vpn, vps

I would like to set up a Few QA servers for a web application, under the app domain, however I would not like these servers to be accessible to just everyone from the Internet.    Ideally, the QA team could authenticated themselves, and then begin testing the web site.

I've been reading about VPNs, would that be an appropriate solution to this problem?  My QA servers are VPSs on digital ocean.    I see there are multiple types of VPN servers as well, so it's not clear what protocol I Should set up, or what steps I should take to get this operational

Thanks

Edit: the Team is completely distributed, so many will be working from their homes

Answer (score 2):

If your QA team is working in the office, you could set up a VPN tunnel between your office and the QA servers, and otherwise leave the QA servers behind a firewall.  Otherwise, you could provide some kind of vpn client software to your QA team and leave the QA servers behind the firewall.

I'm afraid that specific software recommendations are beyond the scope of this site, though, because they become obsolete quickly.  But my guess is that you want a site-to-site tunnel.  You should probably talk to digital ocean about what they support.

In my experience, a VPN is a pretty standard solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.   I should have specified that its a distributed team

Comment: The client software would probably be the most convenient way to implement it, then.